SSRS Migration - The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive
I am migrating (and also combining two separate SSRS servers) into one larger SSRS instance.  I am using the ssrs_migration.rss script and the RS.exe tool (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/sample-reporting-services-rs-exe-script-to-copy-content-between-report-servers?view=sql-server-ver16), but keep running into issues.  The first few folders and reports are migrated successfully, but then I get this error:
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
I've checked out the log files, but that is the extent of the error message.  Nothing shows up in Event Viewer or the regular SSRS log files.
I've attempted to increase different time settings in the reportserver.config file and attempted to migrate one folder at a time to mitigate this, but nothing seems to help.  I had a system engineer disable the firewall just in case that was the issue, but that did not help.  We also adjusted the tls settings and that did not resolve the issue.
I have also tried to use the ReportingServiceTools powershell module.  Using powershell, I can migrate folders and reports, but can't find a way to successfully import subscriptions (there are over 400 that I need to re-connect to reports).
